# Reference suggestion for SVD decomposition

Tags: reference-request, numerical-linear-algebra

I am looking for a reference regarding singular value decomposition for real and complex matrices which would be suitable for the undergraduate level, a book that I was recommended from my numerical analysis lecturer is "Trefethen, Numerical linear algebra", which covers the topic on lesson 31.

Comment: The book you indicate is indeed very good. I strongly advise as well the very clear books written by Gilbert Strang, in particular "Linear algebra and learning from data"

Comment: Perhaps [Matrix Computations](https://www.google.com/search?q=matrix+computations+golub+van+loan) coauthored by [Prof. SVD](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/professor-svd.html) might work as well?